# Spark SaveAsTable Metadata update slow

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am saving a table in Spark using saveAsTable, table is partitioned by two columns and each directory as one file. /part-value1/part2-value-1/part-0000.parquet and /part-value1/part2-value-2/part-0000.parquet. PART1 has 80 partitions and PART2 has 200, so total 16K partitions. Table has been created in the HDFS and but looks like updating hive metastore  is taking time.  Is there any way to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the below commands,

ALTER TABLE table_name RECOVER PARTITIONS - This is faster than refersh

REFRESH table_name - Refresh specific partition option available

INVALIDATE METADATA table_name

Comment: It is spark job and no the impala. Moreover Spark df.saveAsTable is taking time to update metastore

Comment: Add this after your writing part in code. spark.catalog.recoverPartitions(tableName)

Comment: Thanks but not sure how it is going to help, because df.saveAsTable is running for ever ever after files are written to the hdfs. when i see the Spark UI SQL Table, all job ids are finished but still job is running. I am thinking that hive metastore is getting updated.

Comment: if not , you can use spark.stop() in your final block of your code and check.